# Nginx SSL termination proxy to tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, nginx

I want to configure Nginx so that it terminates SSL and then forwards requests to the backend Tomcat servers via http. When I try to login I get redirected back to the app but I get the following exception.

"HTTP Status 500 - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

I am using jasig cas.

Nginx Config

```
#Load balancing group
upstream main_lb_group {
    ip_hash;
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
}

#Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS requests
server {
        listen  80;
        return  301     https://$host$request_uri;
}

#Where users access applications, im using subdomain but it could be the main site
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name subdomain.abc.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://main_lb_group;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}

#Tomcat management page for server 1 has its own subdomain backend1.abc.com
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name backend1.abc.com;

        root /opt/tomcat8b1/webapps/;
        index index.jsp index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
                proxy_connect_timeout       300;
                proxy_send_timeout          300;
                proxy_read_timeout          300;
                send_timeout                300;
        }

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
                expires 1M;
        }
}

#Tomcat management page for server 2 has its own subdomain backend2.abc.com
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name backend2.abc.com;

        root /opt/tomcat8b2/webapps/;
        index index.jsp index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
                proxy_connect_timeout       300;
                proxy_send_timeout          300;
                proxy_read_timeout          300;
                send_timeout                300;
        }

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
                expires 1M;
        }
}
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the cas server had http instead of https in the server name property link. After changing it to https it works fine.